# Azure Data Factory - Use GetRunRecord(runid) to get complete Error Details

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I just tried running a first data copy job inside Azure Data Factory - it failed almost immediately, and displays the message:

> Failed Execution: Error message too large to be returned. Use
>   GetRunRecord(runid) to get complete Error Details.

Can someone tell me where exactly I'm supposed to use this GetRunRecord command?  Googling this error brought me exactly one relevant result, and it was no help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please offer some more details about the datasets and the linked services to and from?

Answer (score 1):

do you have a RunID in your error messages which you could pass to GetRunRecord(runid)?
if yes, you might try the API call described here and pass in the RunID: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/data-factory-slice-run#save-run-log